# Font-Awesome Free 5 Pusdeo not working in FireFox

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-5

I have been trying to update my font-awesome from 4 to 5 and have run into an issue with the Psuedo defnition and FireFox.

I am linking the style sheet `/css/all.min.css`.

**The CSS:**

```
ul.nav-main li.nav-parent > a:after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    content: '\f107';
    color: #abb4be;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 14px 25px;
}
```

Now, struggling for a couple hours I find that it is working on Chrome but not FireFox.  I use the console in FireFox to look at the code and CSS and all the CSS definitions are there.  I uncheck a random definition and *POOF* the icons show up.

This doesn't seem to affect any icons using `<i class="fas circle"></i>` method.

How can I get this to be working in FireFox? :\

Comment: clear your cache in Firefox

Comment: @Temani Afif - That isn't the issue.  However, just to double check, I cleared it and there was no change.  Still not working in Firefox.